# Copy an application data folder to external memory

Tags: android, file-io

I want to build an application that exports user data of another app. The data are stored on /data/data/"name of the app package" . My main problem is how to retrieve the path of that folder to export/copy it later to external memory. As i know, `getFilesDir()` returns the path of the directory holding application files, my own application. But what about other applications data ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access arbitrary data from other applications, unless they store it in a publicly available place like external storage.

Comment: You mean that this folders/files are OS protected? You can just access to your own app data ?

Comment: Yes, otherwise that would invalidate the security model and application sandbox.

Comment: Damn! I was really interested to build that app :(. Anyway, thank you for this information, i didn't know it ;).